# pyshortener error indecipherable ,

Tags: python

I 'm making that mistake here ? For me it is really hidden and do not understand

My code:

```
import tweepy
import random
import time
from random import shuffle
from pyshorteners.shorteners import Shortener
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests


def shortenerUrl(url):
myUrl = url
shortUrlSystem = Shortener('Osdb')
urlReturned = format(shortener.short(myUrl))
return urlReturned


i = random.randint(1, 144)
articleExtractor(i)
for i in listaCompleta:
    api.update_status(status=i)
    time.sleep(random.randint(247, 383))
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mTArt.py", line 73, in <module>
articleExtractor(i)
File "mTArt.py", line 67, in articleExtractor
urlCorta = shortenerUrl(job_url)
File "mTArt.py", line 37, in shortenerUrl
urlReturned = format(shortener.short(myUrl))
NameError: name 'shortener' is not defined
```

then what is the ruling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shortener` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Probably you want to use `shortUrlSystem` which you defined the line above the one with the error.

You should write:

```
urlReturned = format(shortUrlSystem.short(myUrl))
```

## Long Answer

In your code you are trying to call the method `short` on something called `shortener`:

```
urlReturned = format(shortUrlSystem.short(myUrl))
```

Now python knows only about things you **import** and things you **define**.

You **imported** `Shortener` from the module `pyshorteners.shorteners` but python is case sensitive, so `shortener` is not `Shortener`

One of the things you **defined** is `shortUrlSystem`, so python knows about it and you defined it as a `Shortener` object, which happens to have a `short` method (which means you can call `short` on it)

Now looking at the example in the documentation I see

```
url = 'http://www.google.com'
shortener = Shortener('Osdb')
print "My short url is {}".format(shortener.short(url))
```

Here the author **defines** `shortener` as a `Shortener` object, so the command `shortener.short` is valid. But in your code, since `shortener` is not defined, `shortener.short` is not valid, as you can see from the error you posted:

```
NameError: name 'shortener' is not defined
```

Comment: Exactly, but I look for solutions where such errors without coming to mourn to StackOverflow ?
Examples on page Github author at any time recommend using this method , unlike explain as I had put , which is confusing
But excellent reply , it works perfectly .